# Defining class member via a reference passed through constructor

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, assignment-operator, class-members

I am working on a linked list implementation in C++ and I was curious about the lifetime of the original data. Lets say a calling program creates a new ListNode with the following constructor. My concern is the original variable could vary well go out of scope leaving undefined behavior IF the data member assignment is not a copy of value.

```
ListNode<T>::ListNode(const T &value) : data(value) {}
```

When value is passed to data in the parameter list will it define data as a copy of value or will the class member be linked to the original variable passed to the constructor?

EDIT: Adding more information for clarity

**list_node.hpp**

```
template <typename T>
class ListNode
{

friend class List<T>;

public:
   ListNode<T>(const T &);

private:
   T data;

};
```

**list.hpp**

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
   void insert_at_front(const T &);
private:
   ListNode<T> *get_new_node(const T &);
};
```

**list.cpp**

```
void List<T>::insert_at_front(const T &value)
{
   ListNode<T> *new_node_ptr = get_new_node(value);

   ...
}

ListNode<T> *List<T>::get_new_node(const T &value)
{
   return new ListNode<T>(value);
}
```

Comment: It depends on the type of `data`.

Comment: If you want a copy then you should pass by value, not by reference. But of course if `data` is a reference then that won't help.

Comment: Meaning post the declaration of `data`.

Comment: @MarkRansom There's no reason to pass by value here. If you don't care about perf, this is fine, and you don't need to call `std::move`. If you do care about perf, you should have `const&` and `&&` overloads anyhow which are faster.

Comment: @Nir Friedman: When one knows for sure that a copy is needed, then passing by value and then doing `std::move` is pretty good performance-wise and saves the trouble of writing multiple overloads. It is true that one can squeeze a bit more performance out of this by writing those overloads. But stating that "pass-by-value-then-move" approach means "not caring about performance" is far from being accurate.

Comment: @AnT The overloads here are trivial one liners; if you care about performance you just write both and call it a day. If you don't, then you don't. Pass by value also actually performs *worse* for lvalues than pass by const reference. In any case, there are specific situations where pass by value is fine, but it's not particularly good general advice, and it's not good advice for a beginner.

Comment: Downvoting the question without an explanation is extremely helpful. Maybe I should add more context?

Comment: @Nir Friedman: It is the maintenance effort for multiple declarations that makes writing multiple overloads a bit of a chore, even if they are one liners. Again, "caring about performance" is not such a black-and-white thing as you seem to present it. I'd even say that the "pass-by-value" approach should be adopted by default until one is sure that it becomes a performance burden. I'm not sure what you mean by "performs worse for lvalues". The penalty in the "pass-by-value" approach is always just one extra move. Moves are typically very cheap. But yes, they take time.

Comment: Code never written has no bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const Bar& b) : m_b(b) {}

    Bar m_b;    
};

struct Foo2 {
    Foo2(const Bar& b) : m_b(b) {}

    const Bar& m_b;    
};
```

As you can see, the constructor code is the same, but these two classes do something different. The first class will make a copy of the passed `Bar`, so it is "safe" if the local variable passed in goes out of scope. The second class simply grabs the reference. Effectively, this is like holding a reference to the variable that was passed in. So if the variable passed in goes out of scope, then `Foo2` will have a dangling reference.